# Button next page for dataTable look weird

Tags: jquery, text, jquery-plugins, datatables, html-table

I have small issue. I added dataTable plugin in my table.  Assume I have this code for my table.

html:

```
<table id="exist">
...
...
</table>
```

and my jquery:

```
$('#exist').dataTable();
```

the dataTable that I want looking fine, but on button for next and previous button look weird. I am not really sure where should I edit the code. Seems I just used this `.dataTable()` plugin.

this is my table:

[image]

Is there any way to remove this two text `">` `">` ?

**EDITED**

I am referring to this website [dataTable](https://datatables.net/)

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for is the sDom option.
Take a look here: http://datatables.net/usage/options#sDom

For what you want, you should just use "sDom": 't'.

Hope this helps.